# How do i override LIMIT and OFFSET in Peewee?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, peewee

I am trying to build a database driver for Peewee for SQL Server (via SQL Relay). Since SQL Server does not support `LIMIT` syntax like other databases, I need to override this. I believe the correct syntax for SQL Server is something like:

```
SELECT TOP(1) FROM users
```

`TOP` replaces `LIMIT` for queries that only need to return a subset of results found.

On the other hand, in SQL Server, support for pagination of results is done using something like:

```
SELECT email FROM emailTable 
WHERE id=3
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Where `OFFSET <X> ROWS` replaces `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT…` replaces `LIMIT`.

I've also found an old attempt to implement SQL Server support for Peewee, but it looks very outdated as i do not see anything about "query compilers" in the current Peewee codebase.

https://github.com/COUR4G3/peewee-mssql/blob/master/peewee_mssql.py

What might be the best way to customize the query parameters for `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in Peewee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TOP looks like a SQL function, so you can use Peewee's sql function helper (fn):

```
fn.TOP(10)
```

For the offset / fetch next you'll probably need to go fairly deep to manage that... Peewee 3.x contains a complete rewrite of the query builder and SQL generation code, as well as a rewrite of all the AST node classes.

Theoretically you would subclass Select and override the `_apply_ordering()` method, but it's probably going to be complicated and not work exactly right.

To create custom clauses, you will probably do something like:

```
ctx = super(Select, self)._apply_ordering(ctx)
return (ctx
        .literal('OFFSET ')
        .sql(10)
        .literal(' ROWS FETCH NEXT ')
        .sql(10)
        .literal(' ROWS ONLY'))
```

Or use a NodeList:

```
 order = NodeList((
     SQL('OFFSET'),
     Value(10),
     SQL(' ROWS FETCH NEXT '),
     Value(10),
     SQL(' ROWS ONLY'))
 ctx = ctx.sql(order)
```

**EDIT**: I've added an experimental patch which may give you some insight into how to do this. You'll want to override your database class' "get_context_options()" method so that it provides the correct feature flag ("limit_fetch_syntax=True"). Hope this helps:

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/compare/limit-fetch-first?expand=1#diff-eb0556c6b1b9232ba053c4cea13ff075